# Docker build working in my machine but not in Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab

I have a Dockerized Typescript NodeJS aplication and I want to build Docker image from Gitlab CI.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:11.13.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
image: ubuntu:bionic

stages:
  - deploy

before_script:
  # OS dependencies
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y gnupg2
  - apt-get install -y software-properties-common

  # Install docker
  - apt install -y docker.io
  - service docker start

  # Install cURL
  - apt-get install -y curl

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker build -t my_app .
    # more stuff
```

If I run `docker build -t my_app .` in my local **Mac OS**, everything works fine. But in Gitlab CI (**Ubuntu**), it throws these errors in step `RUN npm run build`:

```
src/contact/contact.mapper.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './contact'.
src/contact/contact.repository.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './contact'.
src/contact/contact.resolver.ts(3,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './contact'.
...
```

Docker versions are the same in Gitlab CI and my local. Do I need something else to make it work in Ubuntu (Gitlab CI runner image)?

NOTE: I know Docker in Docker can be used in Gitlab CI, but for some reasons I need to install Docker manually.

**Edit**

Also, if I run `npm run build` in my local (using Node v11.13.0, same version as Dockerfile), it works, too.

**EDIT**

I have just run `docker built -t my_app .` in an Ubuntu machine (using a Vagrant virtual machine) and it doesn't work. So, definitely this errors is about operating system. It works in Mac OS but not in Ubuntu.

Comment: looks like a path issue can you supply your working directory folder hierarchy. src , dist full pathes and also the path of the  directory you run the docker build

Comment: Is `contact` folder checked-in?

Comment: @kichik what do you mean?

Comment: Are you sure all of your source is code is fully committed into your git repository? Did you maybe forget to check-in one of the folders and/or files?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have just cloned the repo again in my local and `docker build` works fine. I think it's related to the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the error. File was actually named `Contact.ts` and not `contact.ts`. It seems that in Mac OS, unlike Ubuntu, paths are case insensitive.